# Can't create an executable of a script using tkinter with pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I have a trivial script which I'd like to convert to a single .exe file. No matter what I do, though, neither py2exe nor pyinstaller can handle including tkinter into the file. As a consequence, a command for pyinstaller like:

```
>python pyinstaller.py --onefile --hidden-import=Tkinter FacebookPhotoRandomizer.py
```

Results in creating the file but then when I try to run it, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter
FacebookPhotoRandomizer returned -1
```

I've tried to make the tkinter import as explicit as it gets so the header part of my script looks like this:

```
import tkinter
import os, imghdr, random, pyperclip
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Though the error persists. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, you have to use `Tkinter` instead of `tkinter` (which would work in Python 3). I think that may be where your problem is coming from.

Comment: Ha, I forgot to start pyinstaller as python3 as opposed to just python which results in using python2 in my system (have them both installed alongside each other). Thanks a lot, replacing python with python3 as the first word of the command in the command line fixed this :)